# How to get the change history from git in specific manner

Tags: git

In git,how should i get complete change history of different releases in sorted order (sorted by release number from beginning to particular stable release) there are situations where the change history of particular release is added later.how to link it with the main path.

Comment: hi, can you provide an example? it's hard to decrypt

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking but I'm 90% sure it has nothing to do with GitHub's API. I'm removing that tag to avoid any confusion

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you are looking for change history for specific release mean you have specific branches. When you are asking for history that means there should 2 datums, One datum is your branch itself and other should ideally be BRANCH_POINT

```
git log BRANCH_POINT..release_branch 

# this will give you changes done SINCE..TO
```